# Error(?) in output of the dd command

Tags: hard-disk, dd

When I run the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=output bs=512 count=1
```

In the middle of the output, I see this text:

```
GRUB ^@Geom^@Hard Disk^@Read^@ Error^M
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are just strings that GRUB has in its bootloader. This doesn't mean that you *have* a hard disk read error, just that GRUB has some text in its bootloader that will be displayed if you do.

Comment: You will see more scary messages fly by as dd stumbles on other programs ;-)